# How to update a data value of a plugin component

Tags: vue.js

I have a date picker plugin---->https://github.com/damienroche/vue-mj-daterangepicker

I want to be able to choose one day on the datepicker by clicking on the date. This function is available if the data propertie 'daySelector' is true. There are no probs to change the value to true. I know about this data propertie and its effect by changing the value on the vue devtol

[image]

My question is can i update this value somehow?

Comment: Right now wat is happening..is it selecting a range of dates?

Comment: exactly! then it expects that i choose another end date. But if the 'daySelector' is on i press one date and the 'to' and 'from' becomes the same day. @Amaarrockz